# Embed a Windows Form in a web browser

Tags: .net, winforms, activex

I have a class which inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form. I need to make the form available via a Web browser. The form currently allows a graph to be generated given various parameters. So embedding it directly in a web page would be ideal for my needs.

How would I go about doing this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are after is XBAP, this allows you to do exactly what you want - embed a Windows Forms application within a browser.

What you do is reference your WinForms application (once compiled as a class library) from a WPF Browser Application.

The WPF Browser Application (a .xbap) can then be embeded in the html, for example as shown below :

```
<html> 
  <head>A page with frames.</head>
    <frameset cols="50%,50%"> 
      <frame src="introduction.htm" > 
      <frame src="XbapEx.xbap" > 
  </frameset> 
</html>
```

See http://www.xbap.org/ or [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970060.aspx) for more information - there are also several good tutorials available on the webs.

Comment: This only works for 'WPF' not 'winforms'. Also, you have to install the XBAP plugin before you can view the page.